# Best Preferred system Configuration to run Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

What configuration does my system require to run jemter with accurate results

Comment: Your question is too broad. What is your definition of "accurate" ? Precision of probes ? Completeness of samples ? You should tell us how your load tests look like. Are you seeking a software configuration (in terms of parameters) or a hardware configuration ?

Answer (score 1):

It depends. Factors are numerous, like:

- how many users you're trying to simulate
- how many postprocessors, assertions, etc. you have in your test
- response size
- is your scenario oriented to simulate "concurrent users" or "hits per second"
- and many others

Given you follow:

1. [JMeter Best Practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)
2. [JMeter Performance and Tuning Tips](https://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/jmeter_performance_tuning_tips/)
3. [Make JMeter behave like a real browser](https://docs.blazemeter.com/customer/portal/articles/1743654-how-to-make-jmeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser)
4. [Use reasonable think times between requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28301300/jmeter-think-time)

You'll be able to simulate several thousands of concurrent users on mid-end hardware like modern laptop.

Comment: good answer to a question which (from my point of view) does not deserve this ;-) Just wanted to add this link https://blazemeter.com/blog because there are lots of very informative posts in this blog.